# If the ball hits your opponent, do you get a point?

Tags: rules, table-tennis

I saw this question: "[Can my body touch the table in table tennis?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/can-my-body-touch-the-table-in-table-tennis)", but I am wondering something far more sinister: if I hit my opponent with the ball, and it doesn't touch the table, do I get a point?

These are the rules: http://www.ittf.com/ittf_handbook/hb.asp?s_number=2%2E10&, but I can't tell if "obstruction by the opponent" includes malicious intent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, yes, it would be your point if it hits your opponent before touching the ground - but only if the ball has not passed the end of the table already.

Rule 2.10.01.03:

> if, after he or she has made a service or a return, the ball touches
>   anything other than the net assembly before being struck by an
>   opponent;

and Rule 2.10.01.04:

> if the ball passes over his or her court or beyond his or her end line
>   without touching his or her court, after being struck by an opponent;

This means after the ball passes beyond the end line (end of the table) - the point is over and whoever hit the ball beyond the end line loses the point.

Obviously if it were legal to win a point just by hitting your opponent with the ball, some crazy strategies would come into play - for the worse of the game.

Comment: +1, and the point is this: When you are playing and the ball is coming toward you, it is your responsibility to make sure that your body is not interfering with the ball's path to the table. If you do interfere, it is a point for your opponent. If the ball has already passed the table and then hits you, it is out, and your point.