# Can my free hand touch the table in table tennis?

Tags: rules, table-tennis

Can my free hand touch the table when hitting a ball in play in table tennis?

Comment: Related question (although not exactly the same): [Can my body touch the table in table tennis?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1229)

Answer (score 6):

No, then you lose the point.

According to [ITTF's Rules](https://ittf.cdnomega.com/eu/2019/08/2019ITTFHandbook_v2.pdf) (The International Table Tennis Federation's Handbook 2019 v2):

> *2.10* A POINT
>
> *2.10.1* **Unless the rally is a let, a player shall score a point**
>
> *2.10.1.11* **if an opponent's free hand touches the playing surface**;